# Targeting two classes and grabbing their value

Tags: jquery

I have two divs

```
<div class="autocomplete-result to" single-result"="" data-index="0"> 
                     Cooma Snowy Mountains  OOM 
                    <br>
                    Cooma ,Australia
 </div>
```

and

```
<div class="autocomplete-result from" single-result"="" data-index="0"> 
                    Lords Heliport
                    <br>
                    Kent,UK
</div>
```

I want to grab the value of the div and since the two classes are different, i want to grab the one with `.from` and then with `.to`.

Here is the code

```
toHandler: function(){
var from = $(".autocomplete-result").text();
this.to = to;
},
```

How can i target `$(".autocomplete-result").text();` with `.from`?

Comment: `var from = $(".autocomplete-result.from").text();var to = $(".autocomplete-result.to").text();`  Not the easiest to find source, but it's in [api.jquery.com/class-selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: @freedomn-m many thanks. You can add this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden away in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) is

> Find the element with *both* "myclass" and "otherclass" classes.
>
> `$( ".myclass.otherclass" )`

Applied to the situation here:

```
var from = $(".autocomplete-result.from").text();
var to = $(".autocomplete-result.to").text();
```

```js
var from = $(".autocomplete-result.from").text();
var to = $(".autocomplete-result.to").text();

console.log(from.trim())
console.log(to.trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autocomplete-result to" single-result="" data-index="0">
  Cooma Snowy Mountains OOM
  <br> Cooma ,Australia
</div>

<div class="autocomplete-result from" single-result="" data-index="0">
  Lords Heliport
  <br> Kent,UK
</div>
```